How to disable WiFi for one user using a GPO
I would like to disable WiFi for one specific user on a PC running Windows 11 Enterprise, while allowing an admin to retain WiFi usability. Preferably, this would be done with an administrative template in the group policy editor. Is there any way to do this? Detailed instructions would be helpful.
I've poked around a lot online, I haven't been able to find an answer that simply disables the WiFi for one user. As an alternative, it would also be acceptable to instead disable any internet connectivity. As well.
This did not help me, only one answer mentions a GPO, and isn't very clear.
